# Serve static files in blazor hosted project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, static-files, blazor

It is a pretty simple Task, I want to use images in my razor pages which are located in `wwwroot/css/images` and use it in html like this.

```html
<img src="~/css/images/logo.png"/>
```

In a normal ASP.Net Core application I would just add `app.UseStaticFiles()` in the  Configure method, but since this is a blazor hosted application, it changes nothing.

I also tried adding the `app.UseStaticFiles()` in the server project, but with no success either.

If you want to try it out yourself just create a blazor-hosted project from the templates and try to serve/display images like I did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blazor serves static file just fine. The issue you’re having is the syntax you’re using to reference the file. You just need to drop the `~` symbol.

```html
<img src="/css/images/logo.png" />
```

Comment: Oh yeah that fixed the issue, is there any reason why I need to drop the tilde? Like what is the relative path in the current context?

Comment: I’ll be honest, I’ve never seen the point of the tilde. You can only load files using either a path relative to the root of the application, in which case start the path with a /. Or from a path relative to the current page, in which case you drop the / from the start of the path. I don’t know the specific reason it’s not valid in Blazor though

Comment: Are the typographic quotes in your answer's source code really correct?

Comment: I don't think they were. That code block was added using the StackOverflow iOS app and that is quotes it uses. I've updated the answer using the Web client now and they appear correct.

Answer (score 0):

One precision about that...the static file root for anything
in blazor starts at the wwwroot folder. wwwroot is
simply taken for granted and is omitted in the actual
path you need to use to ask for a static file. using :

"/css/images/logo.png"

could also be expressed :

"css/images/logo.png"..I'm pretty sure.

If you are in a Razor Class Libray...there is also a wwwroot for
the Razor Class Library itself. When used is a Blazor
Wasm Client the filepath for any static file in the RCL becomes :

"_content/[RCL assembly name]/css/images/logo.png"

Note that even for classes and stuff you implement inside the Razor Class Library itself,
even you are in that library defining stuff...static files
in your own wwwroot inside a Razor Class Library are called using
the "_content/[RCL assembly name]" prefix.